# Appcelerator Titanium: How to enable Mobile Web App development?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

So I'm getting started using the Appcelerator Titanium Mobile framework. I wanted to try out the ability to deploy a mobile web app. However, I can't find any documentation on it. I just installed Titanium Studio and created a new project, but the "deploy to mobile web" checkbox was disabled. There was also a message that said "incompatible Mobile SDK for the Mobile Web support" even though I have the latest version (1.7.2).

What do I need to do in order to enable this feature and get started using Titanium for mobile web app development?

#### Update:

I found the link to the [Titanium Mobile Web documentation](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Mobile+Web+Support).

Turns out the Mobile Web feature is still in beta, which means it's currently only available to paying customers. So I signed up for the indie subscription since it includes a 30-day free trial. I have tried restarting, signing out and signing back in and Titanium Studio still doesn't give me the option to deploy to Mobile Web. What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 1):

I found some additional information on the [Titanium Mobile Web SDK](http://support.appcelerator.com/kb/81/tickets). The reason it doesn't work with Titanium Mobile 1.7.2 is because it doesn't come bundled with Titanium Mobile 1.7.2. You have to download the 1.7.0 RC1 SDK from their Amazon S3 account and manually add it. The link above explains how to do it. I couldn't figure out how to to deploy to an emulator, which kind of defeated the purpose. Also, deploying to Firefox does not work, so don't even try. It only works in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Cool thx, this was a mystery to me too.  They sure are burying this info.